# Eventos en itunes

Tags: java, webservice, api, rest, itunes

¿Es posible hacer que cuando alguien realice el pago de una suscripcion a mi app mediante itunes este se pueda conectar a un endpoint y enviarme la información de la compra en un Json por body como lo hacen los webhooks de [stripe](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks)? he investigado y no he encontrado nada, espero informacion similar a la siguiente :

```
"{
  "created": 1326853478,
  "livemode": false,
  "id": "evt_00000000000000",
  "type": "account.external_account.created",
  "object": "event",
  "request": null,
  "pending_webhooks": 1,
       "api_version": "2015-04-07",
     "data": {
      "object": {
      "id": "ba_00000000000000",
      "object": "bank_account",
      "account": "acct_00000000000000",
     "account_holder_name": "Jane Austen",
      "account_holder_type": "individual",
     "bank_name": "STRIPE TEST BANK",
     "country": "US",
     "currency": "usd",
     "default_for_currency": false,
     "fingerprint": "XPGzUTVJja4EBM9A",
      "last4": "6789",
     "metadata": {
      },
      "routing_number": "110000000",
      "status": "new"
    }
  }
}"
```

No agrego el código de lo que he intentado ya que considero que el como hice el endpoint es irrelevante pues lo que necesito es saber si al menos existe una forma de hacer lo que quiero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se debe ir al [este](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/) enlace e iniciar sesión, seleccionamos la app a la que le queremos agregar el endpoint y en la parte de abajo en  donde dice algo como “
URL del estado de la suscripción” lo agregamos y guardamos.
El Json que el servicio de Itunes manda tiene la estructura siguiente :

```
{
"latest_receipt": "ewoJInNpZ25hdHVyZCI7Cn0=...",
"latest_receipt_info": {
"original_purchase_date_pst": "2018-01-09 12:05:24 America/Los_Angeles",
"quantity": "1",
"unique_vendor_identifier": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
"original_purchase_date_ms": "1515528324000",
"expires_date_formatted": "2018-01-16 20:05:24 Etc/GMT",
"is_in_intro_offer_period": "false",
"purchase_date_ms": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
"expires_date_formatted_pst": "2018-01-16 12:05:24 America/Los_Angeles",
"is_trial_period": "true",
"item_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
"unique_identifier": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
"original_transaction_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
"expires_date": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
"app_item_id": "xxxxxxxxx",
"transaction_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
"bvrs": "2017.12.181617",
"web_order_line_item_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
"version_external_identifier": "825341650",
"bid": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
"product_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
"purchase_date": "2018-01-09 20:05:24 Etc/GMT",
"purchase_date_pst": "2018-01-09 12:05:24 America/Los_Angeles",
"original_purchase_date": "2018-01-09 20:05:24 Etc/GMT"
 },
  "environment": "PROD",
  "auto_renew_status": "true",
  "password": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "auto_renew_product_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "notification_type": "INITIAL_BUY"
}
```